# Java comparator.comparing(o->x).reversed does not work

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, comparator

I have a class Country that implements comparable and have a comparTo method defined.

I'm trying to sort a collection (ArrayList) of Country Items.

```
Collections.sort(Mylist,Comparator.comparing(Country::getCountryName)) // Works
Collections.sort(Mylist, Comparator.comparing(Country::getCountryName).reversed()) // Works
Collections.sort(Mylist, Comparator.comparing(o-> o.getCountryName())) //Works
Collections.sort(Mylist, Comparator.comparing((o-> o.getCountryName())).reversed()) //Does not works
```

I don't understand why the last one does not works, my IDE tells me o is of object type once i add the .reversed() and refuse to call the getCountryName() method.

However it is propperly detected as Country type without the .reversed().

I'm not sure why. Especaly with the :: notation working.

Comment: What's supposed to be a reverse of a comparator?

Comment: @NirAlfasi that's just a comparator inverting the results, i.e. doing a reverse order. In the OP's example it should sort the countries by descending name.

Comment: I'd have to guess here as I currently lack the ability to properly think it through ;) but I'd say that in your latter case type inference doesn't work properly since the lambda doesn't provide the type as the function reference in cases 1 and 2 would to nor can it be inferred from the "assignment" (like in case 3 where the parameter is typed `Country`) since there is no assignment yet. Helping the compiler here would be possible: `comparing((Country o) -> o.getCountryName()).reversed()` should work as should `<Country, String>comparing(o ->o.getCountryName()).reversed())`.

Comment: Wow.I'm going to dig in that syntax. i'm not sure I even understand it but it works.
Thanks.

Comment: Also `Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getCountryName()))` or `Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getCountryName(), Comparator.reverseOrder())` would do. By the way, you don’t need to go to the utility method `Collections.sort(…)` anymore. Nowadays, you can invoke `sort` directly on the list, e.g. `mylist.sort(comparator)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(listePays, Comparator.comparing((Country o) -> o.getCountryName()).reversed())
```

Was the propper syntax. For more explanation see Thomas comments.

or

```
Collections.sort(Mylist, Comparator.<Country, String>comparing(o ->o.getCountryName()).reversed())
```

or as Holger suggested with:

```
Collections.sort(Mylist,Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getCountryName())))
```

or

```
Collections.sort(listePays,Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getCountryName(), Comparator.reverseOrder()))
```